# Timer Continuous Looping

Tags: c#, timer, infinite-loop

I'm passing information from a timer onto another function, but after the information is passed, it keeps passing it. I don't want to turn the timer off.
Is there a way i can stop the loop? The timer interval is 5 seconds.

```
private static List<DirectoryInfo> list_to_copy = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
DirectoryInfo usbdirectory;
backing_up_interface backing_up_interface;
bool newfilesfound = false;

private void usbchecker_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    foreach (DriveInfo usbname in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(usbproperty => usbproperty.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && usbproperty.IsReady))
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + usbname.VolumeLabel + @"\"))
        {
            usbdirectory = new DirectoryInfo(usbname.Name);
            if (!list_to_copy.Contains(usbdirectory))
            {
                list_to_copy.Add(usbdirectory);
                newfilesfound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (newfilesfound == true)
    {
        process_copy();
        newfilesfound = false;
    }
}

//where information is passed to
private void process_copy()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list_to_copy.Count; i++)
    {
        backing_up_interface = new backing_up_interface(list_to_copy[i]);
        backing_up_interface.Show(); MessageBox.Show(list_to_copy[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achive? I mean what is the purpose of this code? You might be unnecessarily complicating it.

Comment: it checks for USB and check if it's already copied. if its not it calls up a function to copy it @qqww2

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it keeps passing it".  what your code is going to do is loop through a collection of drives.  If there is any Directiory that doesn't exits and isn't in your list it will execute the `process_cop()` method once

Comment: Are you sure the copying is always done in under 5 seconds?

Comment: @yhusoonpoint Then why do you use timer? Isn't it enough to check it and start copying just once?

Comment: @mrsargent The timer keeps calling process_copy()

Comment: @TaW yes it is. the interval is 5000

Comment: @qqww2 i need the timer to keep checking it every time

Comment: how long does `process_copy` take to execute?

Comment: Combination of poor English and bad coding. You have a situation where the timer may kick off several times while `process_copy` is still running. You need to set a state machine here...

Comment: @mrsargent every 5 seconds

Comment: _yes it is. the interval is 5000_ So what??? I have a usb copy process running here right now and it will keep running for another 6 hours. ymmv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directory if the file is not found. it will stop it from looping.

Answer (score 1):

if (!Directory.Exists......)
{

}
else
{
return; // stopping the loop from reaching rest of code!
}

Comment: you can break the loop from the second condition either with the same way

Answer (score 1):

You can set some value in the `Timer.Tag` property and use it as a flag to control what should happen in the `Tick` event.

Of course **you** need to know when to set and reset the flag..

`Tag` is of type `object` and can hold anything, including a simple `int` or a nice `Enum`..

In your case I suggest to use at least three state values:

- No New Files
- New Files detected
- Copying in process

I would return directly from the `Tick` while the copying is in progress; do a check otherwise and set the flag when new files are found.

Then set it before and reset it after the copy method call..

But what logic you want to code is up to you.

You actually **are** using a **2-state flag** already; but copy operations may take longer than expected, so one first thing to try is moving `newfilesfound = false;` up before `process_copy();`..but having **three** states would be better, no matter if you store it at class level or with the timer.

Comment: i don't know how to use Timer.Tag and i don't understand how it works.

Comment: It is simply a property, a variable and you can use it like any variable. It doesn't 'work' it simply is a handy spot to put information along with an object, like a Control or a DataRow or here a Timer: `usbchecker.Tag = 1;`or `if (usbchecker.Tag == 0) do something`etc. Your problem is not so much with the Timer but with your control logic, or as code4life noted your state machine, which is not complete imo..

Comment: Well, what do you mean? Did you change your code? If so, __what does it look like now__? If not, why should it change? Also:  try is moving `newfilesfound = false;` up __before__ `process_copy();`..

Answer (score 1):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (Rx) for this. It is basically is an alternative way to create events with tons of operators from making life very easy.

One operator is `Observable.Interval` which effectively sets up a timer, but rather than ticking on a constant basis it will time the interval between when the last handler code ran before the next starts. So if you have a interval of `2` seconds, but your processing takes `X` seconds then there will be a `X + 2` second gap between the starts, if that makes sense.

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
    .Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        foreach (DriveInfo usbname in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(usbproperty => usbproperty.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && usbproperty.IsReady))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + usbname.VolumeLabel + @"\"))
            {
                usbdirectory = new DirectoryInfo(usbname.Name);
                if (!list_to_copy.Contains(usbdirectory))
                {
                    list_to_copy.Add(usbdirectory);
                    newfilesfound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (newfilesfound == true)
        {
            process_copy();
            newfilesfound = false;
        }
    });
```

Just NuGet "Rx-Main".

Answer (score 1):

It keeps looping because the directory doesn't exist so, i made it create a new directory if the directory isn't found. This stopped it from looping.

```
private static List<DirectoryInfo> list_to_copy = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
DirectoryInfo usbdirectory;
backing_up_interface backing_up_interface;
bool newfilesfound = false;

private void usbchecker_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    foreach (DriveInfo usbname in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(usbproperty => usbproperty.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && usbproperty.IsReady))
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + usbname.VolumeLabel + @"\"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + usbname.VolumeLabel + @"\");
            usbdirectory = new DirectoryInfo(usbname.Name);
            if (!list_to_copy.Contains(usbdirectory))
            {
                list_to_copy.Add(usbdirectory);
                newfilesfound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (newfilesfound == true)
    {
        process_copy();
        newfilesfound = false;
    }
}

//where information is passed to
private void process_copy()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list_to_copy.Count; i++)
    {
        backing_up_interface = new backing_up_interface(list_to_copy[i]);
        backing_up_interface.Show(); MessageBox.Show(list_to_copy[i].ToString());
    }
}
```